# How to solve "Error in myFunc[[1]](x, ...)" in R

Tags: r, neural-network, confusion-matrix

I used RSNNS to creat the model

```
x=data[sample(1:nrow(data),length(1:nrow(data))),]
xValues=x[,1:20]
xTarget=decodeClassLabels(x[,21])
x=splitForTrainingAndTest(xValues,xTarget,ratio = 0.3)
x=normTrainingAndTestSet(x)
model=mlp(x$inputsTrain, x$targetsTrain, size=20,
            learnFuncParams = c(0.001), maxit=1000,
            inputsTest =x$inputsTest, 
            targetsTest = x$targetsTest)
```

then, I used confusion matrix to find out the accuracy of training and test set.

```
predictions <- predict(model,x$targetsTest)
confusionMatrix(x$targetsTest,predictions)
```

and the error came out:

```
Error in myFunc[[1]](x, ...) : 
number of input data columns 4 does not match number of input neurons 20
```

I don't know what is the error meaning and how to solve the problem. Please, help me, thank you a lot!!

the part of target  data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHu3W.png)
the part of value data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Z9w.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data. See [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I try to edit my post but still don't know how to do. Could you tell me? thanks.

Comment: The link I provided has many suggestions for improving the reproducibility of your question.